# What is the lifetime of the target of pointer-to-function pointing to a lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer

Sorry, it's a long-winded question, but let me break it down:

Does the C++ standard guarantee that:

```
void (*Ptr)(void) = [] {};
return Ptr;
```

will still be defined behaviour?

I understand that, for a closure, it will be defined, because that closure object is moved/copied by value; but, while I know a 'regular' function has infinite/no lifetime, does the target of Ptr have the same? Or is it destroyed and recreated with each instantiation of the lambda?

The reason I care is, I can't use lambdas as callbacks if not. I want to know.

Comment: Interesting question. Since the pointer will point to some *static* "invoker" member, the static member has no other choice but to use some dummy object to invoke `operator()` of the lambda (becuase the latter is non-static). That dummy should be either local to the "invoker", or static, i.e. it should work fine in the above context. But I don't immediately see that guarantee in the language spec. The language spec does not even postulate the existence of that dummy object.

Comment: @ant Why?  It somply has to run the same code.  Why does it need to be in `operator()`?  `operator()` could be implemented by calling the static function which `operator void(*)()()` returns

Comment: I wish all "long-winded" questions were this short

Comment: I assume you mean to ask: will it be defined behaviour if the calling code then makes a function call through the returned pointer?

Comment: The example in C++14 [expr.prim.lambda]/6 shows that `operator fptr_t` returns the address of a static member function . However, I'm not sure how normative that example is  (technically, since it's in a "Note" it is non-normative)

Comment: @M.M All examples are non-normative, inside a Note or not.

Answer (score 10):

Objects have lifetimes; *functions* do not. Functions don't live or die; they always exist. As such, a function cannot go "out of scope", nor can the function being pointed to by a previously valid function pointer vanish. Regardless of where they come from, function pointers are always valid.

Now, this ignores dynamic loading and so forth, but that's extra-standard behavior.

The function pointer you get back from a lambda is a function pointer. It's not special or magic. It therefore behaves no differently from any other function pointer.

---

> Is it possible that the result of conversion to void (*)() points to something which invokes a member function bound to some object?

That's a much more complex question. One which the C++17 standard seems rather under-specified about, but which C++20 is much more clear on.

The [C++17 standard only says](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#closure-6):

> the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

What "the same effect" means exactly is the question. One could argue that "the same effect" means doing what the function call operator would have done, executing the same sequence of statements. One could also argue that "the same effect" would mean invoking the closure object itself.

The latter case may sound difficult to implement, but remember that compiler magic can be employed. The closure could return an instance-specific function pointer, allocated by the closure upon request. Or some-such.

The C++20 standard is much more clear, in part thanks to the fact that capture-less lambdas can be default constructed:

> the address of a function F that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type's function call operator on a default-constructed instance of the closure type.

So as of C++20, the standard makes it clear that invoking the function pointer is independent of the existence of the lambda object which created it.

Comment: How do member functions fit into this?

Comment: @M.M: Pointers-to-members are a different kind of thing (and are off-topic), but they still follow the same idea. "Members" are not objects. As such, they do not have lifetimes. Member pointers are always valid. However, you still need an object to invoke them on; that object may or may not be valid.

Comment: Member functions are essentially ordinary functions with an extra hidden argument (this). So once you loaded a program all member functions are in their places, but there're no objects yet

Comment: @M.M: Updated the post.

Comment: @NicolBolas cool. Looks like issue 1937 also noticed that this could be better specified.

Answer (score 2):

a lambda function is just a syntactic sugar for a real function or functor (i.e. an object with `operator()` and some members, defined usually in construction time). So, such a function or method is statically defined during compilation.

Although the standard may not specify completely an exact implementation way, as @NicolBolas pointed out, it seems that practical implementations follow the strict guideline: a lambda without a context can be converted to a plain function pointer, no intermediate object is created, neither in the place of lambda defition, nor in the place of invocation. I've just checked it (once again) for gcc and clang and I'm almost sure that MSVC does the same.

**Note**: The rest is about lambdas with contexts, and although for me it seems more interesting and practical case, the question explicitly deals with context-less lambdas.

A context is stored within a lambda (think of a functor object with some meaningful arguments, received on object construction). So, if you pass some references or pointers to the context, these references and pointers (e.g. `this`) won't automagically prolongate lifetimes of their corresponding entities. That's why you should be extra careful, when you save a lambda in a scope other than it was defined in.

See an example of problems related to lambda and its context scope definition in this [resolved issue](https://github.com/jeremyong/Selene/issues/81). Check the fix to see what was done to make stored lambdas with contexts safe.

Comment: "A lambda with an empty context is always transformed into an anonymous static function" What?  No. `auto f=[]{}; static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f),void(*)()>{},"nope");`

Comment: Ok, you're right. But still such a lambda can be assigned to a corresponding pointer to function, as in the topic starter's example.

Comment: Your second para seems to be talking about lambdas with capture, but OP question is about captureless lambda

Comment: I agree with @M.M 's observation, and wanted to add: a lambda that captures cannot decay into a function pointer, so the original question would not make sense. Indeed, the case with a context isn't really more interesting, because we know exactly what happens. This situation is much less clear: is it equivalent to calling a regular function, or is it equivalent to calling a stateless object member function with a dangling `this` pointer (which is UB, but nearly certain to work).

Comment: Well, now the question is transformed into one concerning the standard and UB rather than "practical one". So I see the part about lambdas with context is becoming less and less relevant.