# How long does a non capturing lambda live?

Tags: c++, lambda

If I have some c++ code that looks roughly like this:

```
void (*fun_ptr)(int);

void Test()
{
    fun_ptr = [](int i) { /* do stuff */ };
}

int main()
{
   Test();
   /* do stuff */

   fun_ptr(0);
   return 0;
}
```

Can I expect that function pointer to live forever? Or is it like structs and it's only valid for as long as the lambda declaration is within scope?

The answer in [What is the lifetime of the target of pointer-to-function pointing to a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095613/what-is-the-lifetime-of-the-target-of-pointer-to-function-pointing-to-a-lambda) does not fully adress this question, the linked answer does not explain why scoped lambdas can outlive the scope of the code that created them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fun_ptr` doesn't point to a lambda.

It effectively points to a `static` function (defined in the lambda class), and this function doesn't need a living lambda to work.